# What is the most descriptive way for PUSH / COMET / LONG POLLING to be defined in a WADL

Tags: rest, wadl

I have a WADL where some resources are static requests and other resource utilise COMET / Long polling. Using the WADL standard, how can I differentiate between my static resources and COMET resources?

For continuous integration purposes, client side and server side code is auto generated based on the WADL. Static HTTP requests and COMET requests have different auto generated code, as such defining COMET in the WADL is required.